# IIS website cannot be visited after some time but can visit in server

Tags: iis, server, iis-7.5

I create a website in IIS7.5(server 2008 r2), but the website will cannot visit after some time, maybe one day, maybe some hours. But at this time, the website can be visited in the server, and another website not run in IIS also can be visited

Comment: It can work after recycle the applicationpool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a typical symptom when your web application exhausted the request processing thread pool.

You will have to dig further to see why there are tons of pages being served with bad performance. In most cases it indicates bad web site design.

If you are not capable of digging, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to open a support case.